# trouble using variable inside getElementById

Tags: javascript

I want to convert these codes:

```
if(slidedLcount == 0){
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_1").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_2").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_3").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_4").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_5").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_6").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_7").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_8").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_9").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__item_10").style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__arrow__r").classList.remove("grayedout");
    }
```

to these so it would make it a lot easier, cause will use it mutiple times:

```
if(slidedLcount == 0){
        var x = "0";
        var y = "incredable__offers__examples__item_"
        while(x<10){
            var z = y+x;
            document.getElementById(z).style.cssText = "animation-name: SlideL_first;";
            x = (x*1)+1;
        }
        document.getElementById("incredable__offers__examples__arrow__r").classList.remove("grayedout");
    }
```

but getting this error

> mainscript.js:67 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of
>   null

Comment: Your `x` should be started from `1` instead of `0` as a first look.

Comment: And the condition in the loop should be `<= 10` not `< 10`

Comment: And why is `x` a string? It will be automatically converted into a string if you "add" it to `y`

Comment: Why not use a `class` to select them all?

Comment: Leave your x as number. While concatenation (+) it'll be automatically coerced in a string. And start your x with 1 and make the loop till x <= 10

Comment: thank you all, Ivar that is a great Idea, didn't know I can select all using class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, x should start from 1 not 0, stupid mistake from my side!